# Error en MySQL/Netbeans

Tags: mysql-workbench, netbeans-8.2

*Buenos días*:

Estoy realizando un proyecto (tesis) de control de stock para una sucursal de una panadería, el problema que se me presentó fue al momento de cargar un PRODUCTO en la tabla DEVOLUCIONES me salía el siguiente error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (´provincia1´.´devolucion´,CONSTRAINT´id_producto´FOREIGN KEY(´id_prod´)REFERENCES ´producto´(´id_producto´))

Luego de buscar a que se debía el problema, acá en la página en un post parecido a mi duda dieron una solución lo apliqué en el código y funcionó. PERO ahora el problema es que guarda la devolución - en MySQL - pero no me muestra en el cuadro devoluciones del proyecto...

adjunto parte de la base de datos:

```
create table if not exists Producto
(
id_producto int not null primary key auto_increment,
nombre varchar(30) not null,
categoria varchar(40) not null,
precio float not null default '0',
stock int(30) not null default '0',
estado varchar(10) not null
);

create table if not exists Devolucion
(
id_devolucion int not null primary key auto_increment,
id_prod int not null,
nombre varchar(30) not null,
cantidad varchar(30) not null default '0',
precio float not null default '0',
detdev varchar(30) not null,
constraint id_produc
foreign key (id_prod) references Producto(id_producto)
);
```

***ACTUALIZO** corregí la forma en que relacioné la tabla Devoluciones con Producto - como lo había hecho al principio - estuve mirando nuevamente mi código **PERO no logro encontrar el porqué no me muestra en el proyecto lo que guardo?***

*el código para mostrar los datos que voy cargando es el siguiente (apliqué el mismo para que me muestre cuando voy cargando datos por ejemplo en la tabla Productos, Clientes y funciona):*

```
  public DefaultTableModel mostrar(String buscar) {

    DefaultTableModel modelo;

    String[] titulos
            = {"Codigo devolucion","CODIGO PROD", "NOMBRE ",
                "PRECIO","CANTIDAD",
                "DETALLE DEVOLUCION"};

    String[] registros = new String[6];
    totalRegistros = 0;
    modelo = new DefaultTableModel(null, titulos);

   sSQL = "SELECT id_devolucion ,id_prod,"
            + "(SELECT nombre FROM Producto WHERE id_prod = id_producto)AS productoNom, "
            + " Replace(Format(precio, 0), ',', '.') as precio ,cantidad,"
            + "(SELECT stock FROM Producto WHERE id_prod = id_producto)As "
            + "stock , detdev as detalleDev FROM Devolucion WHERE detdev like '%" + buscar + "%' "
           + " ORDER BY id_devolucion ASC ";

    try {

        Statement st = cn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sSQL);

        while (rs.next()) {

            registros[0] = rs.getString("id_devolucion");
            registros[1] = rs.getString("id_prod");
            registros[2] = rs.getString("productoNom");
            registros[3] = rs.getString("precio");
            registros[4] = rs.getString("stock");
            registros[5] = rs.getString("detalleDev");

            totalRegistros = totalRegistros + 1;
            modelo.addRow(registros);
        }
        return modelo;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, e);
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: entoces el problema seria la consulta que muestra los registros que mencionas

Comment: El que te haya recomendado eso que se lo haga mirar. Si `id_devolucion` va a ser FK de Producto NUNCA debe ser `auto_increment`